# Display values searched for but not original value

Tags: sql

I am writing a query in SQL that uses the IMDB database.  It needs to display all the actors that starred in movies with Kevin Bacon--without displaying Kevin Bacon.  I have a list of all the actors, but it includes Kevin Bacon.  I do not know how to not display his name.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT name
FROM people 
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id 
             FROM stars 
             WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                                FROM stars 
                                WHERE person_id IN (SELECT id 
                                                    FROM people 
                                                    WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" 
                                                          and birth = "1958")));
```

I had to include the birth year as there was multiple Kevin Bacons on the list.

Comment: what's the database schema?  Seems better approached with a `JOIN`

Comment: My original query works except I need to search using Kevin Bacon but not display Kevin Bacon in my final results.

Comment: I played around with it and found: GROUP BY name HAVING name != "Kevin Bacon" worked....it alphabetized the list but thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

Simpy exclide Kevin from the result set

```
SELECT name
FROM people 
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id 
             FROM stars 
             WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                                FROM stars 
                                WHERE person_id IN (SELECT id 
                                                    FROM people 
                                                    WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" 
                                                          and birth = "1958")))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id 
               FROM people 
               WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" and birth = "1958");
```